# Errors, the application was unable to start, python is not defined, pip is not defined

Tags: python

i m tired installing python i m trying to install python 3.7.1 but not working nor 3.8.3, i have tried so many times but all in vain, sometimes it gets started but then not working, now it is installed but showing Error unable to start the application and when i type python in command prompt it says name error python is not defined.

Comment: You need to setup the system variable path for pip and python.

Comment: You need to provide more details.  What operating system are you using? How are you trying to install Python?